# Custom animation triggers twice

Tags: android, animation

I have a listener that listens and makes focused items little bit bigger with animation.

```
private fun focus() {
    itemView?.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            val anim : Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(itemView.context, R.anim.scale_in)
            itemView.startAnimation(anim)
            anim.fillAfter = true
        } else {
            val anim : Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(itemView.context, R.anim.scale_out)
            itemView.startAnimation(anim)
            anim.fillAfter = true
        }
    }
}
```

Besides this listener I also made custom function, that when focused item is clicked, it actually changes size back to normal

```
fun customFunction(): Unit = with(itemView) {
    val anim : Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(itemView.context, R.anim.scale_out)
    itemView.startAnimation(anim)
    anim.fillAfter = true
}
```

**PROBLEM:** `focus()` and `customFunction()` functions work alright. Problem is, when I hit enter on focused element (customFunction() triggers) and element changes it size to normal - which is okay. But the moment I navigate to other element, the previous one scales out twice. How do I need to modify my onFocusListener to know that I shouldn't scale out twice if I've triggered customFunction() by clicking some item. Any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right your question you may have to try : `itemView. setOnFocusChangeListener(null);` in your `customFunction()`